# Unable to update balance after deposit transaction in ATM interface

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc

I'm doing a project on ATM interface in Java using Java swing for GUI. I'm not able to update the balance after the deposit transaction in the database. I'm not able to find where I'm going wrong.

I've a database named - TYProject, in it the table is - `customerDetails` and in it there's `cardnum`, `cardpin` and `balance` as columns. Actually I'm getting an error as parameter index out of range 1> number of parameters which is 0. I'm sending my code of deposit module.

### Code:-

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    int depositAmount = Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
    int cardnum = Integer.valueOf(jTextField2.getText());

      try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TYProject","root","riddhimore");
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from customerDetails where cardnum=?");
        pst.setInt(1, cardnum);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            rs.getInt("balance");
            String sql = "update customerDetails set balance=balance+"+depositAmount+ "where cardnum=?"; 
            PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1,cardnum);
            if(pst1.executeUpdate() == 1){
                int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to submit ?", "Confirm ?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if(a == 0){
                    new atmFrame10().setVisible(true);
                    this.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
      }catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      }
}
```

Comment: Not your current issue, but watch out for that update query. You should put a space before "where".

Comment: About the problem you're asking about, what line does it say has the error?

Comment: `String sql = "update customerDetails set balance = ? where cardnum = ?"; ` should be your statement. You need to get the correct balance first, instead of discarding it, as you are at the moment. `Connection` and `PreparedStatment` should be in try-with-resources. Don't `SELECT *` - that's just wasteful

Comment: You're committing a class new programmer mistake: All your code in a single class/method.  I don't like seeing database code in methods with Swing UI.  You can't test them independently.  You shouldn't be hard coding database connections in code.  Externalize them in configuration so you can change them without modifying your code.

Comment: Thank you for ur responses. I tried putting space near where clause in sql query but no results...

Comment: Can u elaborate more on ur answer - Federico klez Culloca. Sorry if I've pronounced ur name wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I'm getting an error as parameter index out of range 1> number of parameters which is 0.

To avoid the `IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` (or whatever it is called) I have made a habit of using a ternary operators. This acts as insurance to make sure you aren't calling an index out of bounds:

```
int index = (testNumber < 0 || testNumber > numOfParameters) ? 0 : testNumber;
```

This translates to:

```
if("the index number is outside the range of your Array/Object/etc.") 
    return 0; 
else 
    return testNumber;
```

**EDIT for clarification**

I understand that this is not a full solution to

> Unable to update balance

but advice to avoid some exceptions